# What is the idiom used when you don't do something right away but do it eventually?

Tags: idiom-requests

What idiom can I use to describe a situation where I didn't do something I should have done at a certain point of time but did it eventually ?

Comment: Are you looking for “*I’ll get around to it*”. Or in your case “I finally got around to it”

Comment: The word for what you're describing is "procrastinate."  An idiom that relates to procrastination is "A stitch in time saves nine," or you can say, "I drug my heels getting that done."

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're looking for? It's not clear if you want (for example) an idiom for the regret you feel for only finishing something after it's due, or an idiom that looks at the positive side (because you could have simply not done it at all), or an idiom with some other connotation. Please [edit] this information and an example sentence (or more) where you would use this idiom so that your question can be answered. Thanks.

Comment: @Billy As i understand it, _procrastinate_ says something about the reason behind postponing something, and nothing about whether or not you actually get around doing it. If for instance you didn't do it in time because of an actual impediment, _procrastinate_ couldn't be used to describe that situation.

Comment: "Procrastinate" does not say anything about the reason behind delaying doing something.  Also, whether impediments are "actual" or just excuses are like beauty -- in the eye of the beholder.  When one agrees to or is obliged to complete a task by a given time in the future, a deadline, there is a general understanding that one gets it done regardless of what comes up because stuff always comes up.  It's a matter of integrity, and delaying to the point of risking your integrity and not getting it done because something then comes up, like it generally does, is called "procrastinating."

Answer (score 13):

You could use ***“[Better late than never](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/better-late-than-never)”.***

> said when you think that it is better for someone or something to be late than never to arrive or to happen.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: Odd to find out that [there's a precisely identical expression in French](https://www.fluentu.com/blog/french/french-idiomatic-expressions/) but [this dictionary of proverbs](https://archive.org/stream/DictionaryOfProverbs_201303/Dictionary-of-Proverbs_djvu.txt) says it probably goes back to at least Latin. I like the retort '**...but better still is never late**'.

Answer (score 4):

If the person feels guilty that things didn't go as planned, [@Scott is right with 'better late than never'](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/453650/171986).

On the other hand, **if the person felt the *schedule* was the problem in the first place**, there's

> ## [(in) one's (own) sweet time](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20one%27s%20(own)%20sweet%20time)
>
> as slowly as one wants even though others want one to act more quickly
>
> > "You took your own sweet time turning this in."
> > "Well, [wildly implausible medical/familial/national-security excuse]."
> > "Yeah, well, you're still losing 20 points."

Answer (score 1):

I must say that the expression [**at long last**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/at-long-last) (or simply **at last**) fits your description fairly well too, but whether it is the perfectly fit for your particular situation really depends on the context of the situation which you have not provided:

> finally, after difficulty, delay, or irritation

Example:

> **At long last**, I managed to finally get it done! Phew... What a relief!

Answer (score 0):

Prioritization is the word for which you are looking.  I do not know if you would call that an idiom or not.

Comment: Maybe something like '*non*prioritization'...